JSON request in C with HTTP
I'm trying to make a JSON request in C with HTTP, but whenever I run my code it returns that there are no values ​​to be processed. I changed the https and accesskey path for security reasons
void sendAPI(const char *json) {
    CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (!curl) {
        finish_with_error("Falha ao inicializar cURL");
    }

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://monitoramento.loralora/api/");

    struct curl_slist *headers = NULL;
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Content-Type: application/json");
    headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "acesskey: 49046a182af34gase52dfdbe8637940");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json);

    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if (res != CURLE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Erro na requisição cURL: %s\n", curl_easy_strerror(res));
    }

    curl_slist_free_all(headers);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}


    switch (tipoLeitura) {
        case 0:
            if (getRead()) {                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
                sprintf(json, "{\"SensorId\":\"%s\",\"codeVersion\":\"%s\",\"Measures\":                [{\"SensorComponentId\":\"%s_volh\",\"Measure\":%5.2f}, {\"SensorComponentId\":\"%s_cht\",\"Measure\":%5.2f}, {\"SensorComponentId\":\"%s_prem\",\"Measure\":%5.2f}, {\"SensorComponentId\":\"%s_ahp\",\"Measure\":%5.2f}, {\"SensorComponentId\":\"%s_bt\",\"Measure\":%5.2f}, {\"SensorComponentId\":\"%s_lt\",\"Measure\":%5.2f}]}", sensorID, version, sensorID, HeliumLevel, sensorID, ColdHeadTemperature, sensorID, MagnetPressure, sensorID, AverageHeaterPower, sensorID, BoreTemperature, sensorID, LinkTemperature);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if ((unsigned)strlen(json) > 0) {
        // printf("JSON a ser enviado: %s\n", json);
        sendDataSensor(json); // Envia o JSON via HTTP POST
    }

I've only tried an API connection test and it worked, I had no problems, I only had problems sending the information via JSON.

Aside: There's no need to cast the result of strlen() to unsigned. It returns size_t, which is already unsigned.

It would be better to use a JSON library instead of using sprintf() to create the JSON, in case the data needs to be escaped.

It would be worthwhile to enable sufficient logging at the server to examine the request bodies that are actually being received there.  Those will at least help you narrow down the nature of the issue.

Is "acesskey" supposed to be spelled like that?

In general, use snprintf() instead of sprintf() to avoid buffer overflow.
